# How to get an error message for errno value in python?

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, errno, system-calls

I am using the **ctypes** module to do some ptrace system calls on Linux, which actually works
pretty well. But if I get an error I wanna provide some useful information. Therefore I
do an **get_errno()** function call which returns the value of errno, but I didn't found 
any function or something else which interprets the errno value and gives me an associated
error message.

Am I missing something?
Is there a ctypes based solution?

Here is my setup:

```
import logging
from ctypes import get_errno, cdll
from ctypes.util import find_library, errno

# load the c lib
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("c"), use_errno=True)
...
```

Example:

```
 return_code = libc.ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, None, None)
 if return_code == -1:
   errno = get_errno()
   error_msg = # here i wanna provide some information about the error
   logger.error(error_msg)
```

Comment: Did you look at the `errno` package?  What was missing, incomplete or confusing?  http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This prints `ENODEV: No such device`.

```
import errno, os

def error_text(errnumber):
  return '%s: %s' % (errno.errorcode[errnumber], os.strerror(errnumber))

print error_text(errno.ENODEV)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import errno
>>> import os
>>> os.strerror(errno.ENODEV)
'No such device'
```